# $.ajaxFileUpload successfully uploads file to a folder but wasn't able to pass values to be saved in the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have used ajaxfileupload upon form submission of my form. This is also for uploading purposes for image files. The image was successfully uploaded, however other data to be saved to database wasn't been included? Because it leaves my table fields blank, so I was thinking the values wasn't been passed to the category_save.php. I also observed that when I used the `$.ajax({})` instead of `$.ajaxFileUpload`, the data were all successfully passed and saved in the database including the image file name but the actual file wasn't been uploaded at all. But when I used the `$.ajaxFileUpload` instead of `$.ajax({})`, it just work reverse, the file was uploaded but the values wasn't been saved in the database. What is the wrong with this? Here are my codes:

product_form.php

```
<form method="post" name="new_category" id="product_category" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
 <ul class="add_prod">
 <li>Category Title:<input type="text" name="category[title]" id="cat_title" value="" placeholder="Title" /> </li>
 <li>Category Description:<textarea rows="4" cols="40" name="category[description]"></textarea></li>
 <li>Category Image:<input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" /></li>
 </ul>  
 </form>
```

product1.js

```
$("#product_category").submit( function(){

  event.preventDefault();  
   var data_category = $(this).serialize();
   var image = $("#image_file").val();

$.ajaxFileUpload
    (
        {
            type:"post",
            url:"../wp-content/plugins/product_form/category_save.php",
            secureuri:false,
            fileElementId:'image_file',
            dataType: "json",
            data:data_category + "&image_file=" +image,                
            success: function (data)
            {
               if(data.notify == "Success"){
               console.log(data.notify);
              }
             else{
                return false;
              }
            }  
        }
    ); 
 });
```

product2.js

```
$("#product_category").submit( function(){
  event.preventDefault();  
   var data_category = $(this).serialize();
   var image = $("#image_file").val();

     $.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url: "../wp-content/plugins/product_form/category_save.php",
       dataType: "json",
       data:data_category + "&image_file=" +image,
       success: function(data){
           if(data.notify == "Success"){
               console.log(data.notify);
           }
           else{
               console.log(data.notify);
           }
       } 

   });

});
```

category_save.php

```
<?php 
 //establish connection
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ion2_emagi"); 
 //on connection failure, throw an error
 if(!$con) {  
  die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error()); 
  } 

 $output_dir = "C:/Users/Employees/Dropbox/emagi/wp-content/plugins/product_form/img/";
 $file_name = "image_file"; 

 if(isset($_FILES[$file_name]))
  {
  //Filter the file types , if you want.
  if ($_FILES[$file_name]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
 else
 {  
    //move the uploaded file to uploads folder;
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image_file"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.     $_FILES["image_file"]["name"]);
 }

}

//get the form elements and store them in variables
$category_values = $_POST["category"]; 
$image_url = basename($_POST["image_file"]);
$image_field = "image_url";
$data = array();

//unset($view_all_info['Password2']);
  foreach($category_values as $field => $val){
 $data[] = "`".$field."` = '".$val."'";
 }

 array_push($data,"`".$image_field."` = '".$image_url."'");

 $sql = "INSERT INTO wp_product_category SET ".implode(',', $data);
 $ret = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

if($ret){
$notification="Success";
}
 else{
 $notification="Failed";
 }

echo json_encode(array('notify'=>$notification));

mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` field should have this format:

```
data: { data_category: data_category,  image_file: image_file }
```

You are trying to pass it as a URL with parameters instead.

Then you have to retrieve it in PHP with `POST` by the name of the parameter. For example:

```
$category_values = $_POST["data_category"];
```

Comment: @Eli_jun not needed. You can take a look at examples at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: The image filename works. It is there now in the database but the other data is not yet saved still

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong somewhere else. This is the way to do it. Verify your other data.

Comment: I alert my data_category but the values are there. This values also are saved when I used the product2.js .

Comment: @Eli_jun then check your PHP, check your SQL, check other things. The problem migth not be in the jQuery.

Comment: I am confused with this

Comment: Make sure you are receiving it well in PHP. Use an echo or a return in PHP before executing anything and then `alert` or use `console.log` for the returned `data` in jQuery. Then try to execute manually the SQL insert statement with the values you are trying to add